# How could i buy a package of sms verification codes to verify my mobile application.?

Tags: verification, sms-verification

I am facing a problems to send the sms verification codes to my mobile application users,
Since some of telecom operators are blocking these kind of sms and not allowing the users to receive such sms,
So i am looking for verification code messeges provider to serve me in all over the countries (**not blocked by local mobile networks operators**) 
The cost should be affordable not expensive, to use for mobile app verfication. Can you advise me how to do.?

Comment: You need to be much more specific and provide relevant detail to get an answer. What are you trying to accomplish? what language/framework are you using? how is it being served?

Comment: Sorry I am not original English speaker, so I know my English is weak, so please do excuse me.

Comment: Your written english is good, but you are too vague for anyone to be able to give you a usseful answer. Please read my earlier comment and edit your question, otherwise You probably will not get an answer...

Comment: What about now.? After editing

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little unsure whether this will solve your issue, but here is a suggestion. Search for two factor authentication providers on Google. There are several to choose from. Some of them offer trial plans so that you can test them. You have not stated clearly whether it is internationally you want to use this, or in certain countries. I would presume that the issue can be that a very inexpensive sms provider will not send international sms messages, due to the cost involved. I am not familiar with any blocking of such messages, so an example of your situation (e.g. Carrier or country, and the service you have already tried using) could make it easier to help.

The more information you provide in a question on so, the easier it is to get good help.